# Why is Apache ignoring :80 vhost file and only matching sites in :443 vhost file?

Tags: apache, centos, redhat, vhosts

I have 2 vhost files:  1 with all our sites admin URLS on port 443, 1 with all our sites main URLs on port 80.
Both files are known by apache as shown by apachectl -S.
net stat shows Apache listening on :80 and :443

I am using host file from my MacBook for now.

However, only URLs that match vhosts lines in the 443 vhost file are working.  Otherwise the site will load the first site in the 443 vhost file. (301 Moved Permanently)

I even try going to site-name.com:80 - but none of the site URLS from the :80 vhost file are getting matched by apache.  What am I missing?

EDIT:  adding code

`Listen 1xx.2xx.3xx.4xx:80` is defined in httpd.conf

From vhost.conf for main site URLS (This one is NOT working)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost 1xx.2xx.3xx.4xx:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com/public
    ServerName site1.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/site1.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/site1.com-access_log common
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"
<Directory /var/www/site1.com/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

From sslvhost.conf for admin sites (This one IS working)

```
Listen 443 https

NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/site1.com/public"
ServerName site1.com
ServerAlias site1.com admin-site1.com

LogLevel warn

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"

SSLEngine on

SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"


<Directory /var/www/site1.com/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Without any config file, it's hard to tell, what's wrong. Post the relevant parts at least.

Answer (score 0):

From the config it seems you are missing the following

```
Listen 80
```

You Can add it just below the `NameVirtualHost *:80`